# Clap derive fails

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, clap

I am creating a project in Rust and just wanted to add a command line parser using [clap](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/).
However, my project fails to build:

`args.rs`

```
use clap::Parser;

/// Simple program to greet a person
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
pub struct Args {
    /// Optional name to operate on
    #[clap(short, long, value_parser)]
    width: usize,

    /// Sets a custom config file
    #[clap(short, long, value_parser)]
    height: usize,

    /// Turn debugging information on
    #[clap(short, long, value_parser)]
    mines: u8,
}
```

`Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "rustymines"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rand = "*"
grid = { git = "https://github.com/conqp/grid.git", branch = "main" }
clap = { version = "3.2.22", features = ["derive"] }
```

Error:

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling libc v0.2.133
   Compiling version_check v0.9.4
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.44
   Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.4
   Compiling quote v1.0.21
   Compiling syn v1.0.101
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
   Compiling ppv-lite86 v0.2.16
   Compiling heck v0.4.0
   Compiling os_str_bytes v6.3.0
   Compiling hashbrown v0.12.3
   Compiling termcolor v1.1.3
   Compiling once_cell v1.15.0
   Compiling strsim v0.10.0
   Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
   Compiling textwrap v0.15.1
   Compiling grid v0.1.0 (https://github.com/conqp/grid.git?branch=main#227750b9)
   Compiling proc-macro-error-attr v1.0.4
   Compiling proc-macro-error v1.0.4
   Compiling clap_lex v0.2.4
   Compiling indexmap v1.9.1
   Compiling getrandom v0.2.7
   Compiling atty v0.2.14
   Compiling rand_core v0.6.4
   Compiling rand_chacha v0.3.1
   Compiling rand v0.8.5
   Compiling clap_derive v3.2.18
   Compiling clap v3.2.22
   Compiling rustymines v0.1.0 (/home/rne/Projekte/rustymines)
error[E0616]: field `width` of struct `args::Args` is private
  --> src/game.rs:26:24
   |
26 |         Self::new(args.width, args.height, args.mines)
   |                        ^^^^^ private field

error[E0616]: field `height` of struct `args::Args` is private
  --> src/game.rs:26:36
   |
26 |         Self::new(args.width, args.height, args.mines)
   |                                    ^^^^^^ private field

error[E0616]: field `mines` of struct `args::Args` is private
  --> src/game.rs:26:49
   |
26 |         Self::new(args.width, args.height, args.mines)
   |                                                 ^^^^^ private field

error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `parse` found for struct `args::Args` in the current scope
  --> src/game.rs:30:26
   |
30 |         let args = Args::parse();
   |                          ^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `args::Args`
   |
  ::: src/game/args.rs:6:1
   |
6  | pub struct Args {
   | --------------- function or associated item `parse` not found for this
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
   |
1  | use clap::Parser;
   |

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0599, E0616.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `rustymines` due to 4 previous errors
```

Note that none of the errors should happen, since, according to the linked clap cookbook, clap should work some magic and make the fields publicly accessible as well as implement the `parse()` function.
What's the issue here?

PS:

```
$ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/rne/.rustup

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.63.0 (4b91a6ea7 2022-08-08)
```

Comment: did you read "help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
   |
1  | use clap::Parser;"

Comment: plus "clap should work some magic and make the fields publicly accessible" care to quote that cause that a no for me

Comment: As you can see in the code, I actually *do* use the imported `use clap::Parser;` with the macro directive `#[derive(Parser)]` as per the [documentation](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/).

Comment: I doubt you also have a `use clap::Parser;` in `src/game.rs` file.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=547e4b49ecffbdaf0a18bb2cbe6a4fc1

Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Agree with @Stargateur, you need `use clap::Parser` both in the file where you **define** the `Args` struct and in the file where you **use** it.

Comment: @Stargateur,Finomnis That was it. For me as a Rust noob, this was not at all obvious. I'd have to look into why I need to include that twice.

Comment: I also needed to make the fields `pub` to be able to access them. I have mistakenly believed, that the macros would take care of this. A lot of pitfalls, if you do not implement it in one unit file like the example.

Comment: @RichardNeumann It is indeed not obvious why you have to `use clap::Parser`, I have to agree. It's quite specific to `clap`. If you don't want that, encapsulate the `Args::parse()` call in a function called `parse_args()` or similar directly in the `args.rs` file. Then you can call this function without having to `use clap::Parser`. Like here: https://github.com/Finomnis/rust-tokio-template/tree/824285f9aa573c53f40efe48f521ca1936adad0a/template/src

Comment: In general, if you want to use a trait function of an object, the trait itself has to be in scope. It's one of those things that are confusing to Rust beginners that come from a different language, because the concept of adding functionality to an existing type is just not something that exists in most other languages.

Comment: @RichardNeumann Having to make them `pub` is expected, though. You can't access them otherwise, with or without `clap`.